# Вывод двух коллекций в консоль c#

Tags: c#, list, консоль

**Добрый день!**

У меня есть две коллекции `IEnumerable<Repo>` и `List<string>`. 
**Есть два метода, которые возвращают эти коллекции.**

```
public IEnumerable<Repo> CollectionWithUrl()
{   
    StreamReader jsonfile = new StreamReader("file.json");
    string json = jsonfile.ReadToEnd();
    IEnumerable<Repo> repos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Repo>>(json);
    return repos;
}

public List<string> CollectionWithHash()
{
    Repo CollWU = new Repo();
    var CollWithURL = CollWU.CollectionWithUrl();
    List<string> listHashRepo = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in CollWithURL)
    {
        listHashRepo.Add(item.GetHash(item.url.ToString()));
    }
    return listHashRepo;
}
```

**А я пытаюсь их вывести в консоль таким способом:**

```
Repo printhash = new Repo();
var printhashvar = printhash.CollectionWithHash();

Repo printurl = new Repo();
var printurlvar = printurl.CollectionWithUrl();

Console.WriteLine("CollectionWithHASH");
Console.WriteLine(printhashvar);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("CollectionWithURL");
Console.WriteLine(printurlvar);
Console.WriteLine();
```

**И они не выводяться в консоле. Хотя в первой коллекции должны быть хэш-коды, а во второй ссылки!**
**А пишется в консоле:**

> `CollectionWithHASH`
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ConsoleAppOOP.Repo]`
>   `CollectionWithURL`
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`

**Помогите решить проблему. Спасибо!**

Comment: выводите в цикле в `foreach` например

Comment: С коллекцией list всё получилось. С коллекцией IEnumerable - нет

Comment: а Вы покажите объект `Repo`, просто не понятно, что там у Вас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно Вашему коду, необходимо немного его модифицировать, вот так:

```
Repo printhash = new Repo();
var printhashvar = printhash.CollectionWithHash();

Repo printurl = new Repo();
var printurlvar = printurl.CollectionWithUrl();

Console.WriteLine("CollectionWithHASH");
printhashvar.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("CollectionWithURL");
printurlvar.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x./*к примеру имя поля из Repo*/));
Console.WriteLine();
```

К примеру, если у Вас в классе `Repo` есть поле `Description`, то будет вот так:

```
printurlvar.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Description));
```

Внутрь `Console.WriteLine` передавать строку, а не коллекцию. И для коллекции `IEnumerable` сделать `.ToList()`, чтобы вызвать `.ForEach(`.

Как правильно заметил @VladD, лучше не использовать `ToList` для потенциально большой коллекции, а выводить через `foreach, in`. Я с этим согласен поэтому просто с помощью `foreach, in` делать перебор коллекции и выводить вот так:

```
foreach (var el in printurlvar)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el. /*ну и выводимое поле*/);

    // если нужно вывести несколько элементов, то вот так:
    Console.WriteLine($"Имя:'{el.Name}' Описание:'{el.Description}'");
    // при наличии "Name" и "Description" в классе "Repo" для примера

    // либо следующим способом:
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Имя:'{0}' Описание:'{1}'", el.Name, el.Description));
    // вариантов достаточно много
}
```

Почитать для ознакомления можно это:

1. [foreach, in (Справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)
2. [Метод List.ForEach (Action)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1, но я бы не использовал `ToList` для потенциально большой коллекции, а выводил бы через `foreach`.

Comment: @VladD, а я тут как раз дополнял обычным `foreach, in`

Comment: @DenisBubnov Благодарю!

Comment: Очень странно, даешь ответ, он вроде правильный, помог решить проблему другому человеку и получаешь минус непонятно за что и непонятно от кого.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Я минус не ставил!

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans, да я знаю, я же говорю, что кто-то мимо проходил и поставил. Вам, кстати, тоже поставили минус, я заметил, было в один момент. Ну ладно, буду надеяться, что в другой раз пояснят *почему?* ))) бывает